# What is the purpose of the commands #, $, and -l?

Tags: shell-script

Also, the following is part of a .bat file that I was given. I thought that file format is for a Windows script, but the following is a Unix shell script, is it not? So what is the difference between this and a .sh file?

```
#PBS  -l mem=900mb,walltime=25000:00:00,cput=25000:00:00,nodes=1:ppn=1
cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR

./sample_file.x > tmp
```

Comment: So far as your local shell is concerned, the line beginning with `#` is a comment - however the script is likely intended for use with a [Portable Batch System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Batch_System) scheduler

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks, I know this is very basic... but when I change the value of ppn and submit the calculation, it changes the number of processors that I am using, so I don't understand how that is just a comment.

Comment: @Gnovice It's a comment because it's an instruction that the batch system (PBS) uses. It's not a shell command.  Other queuing/batch systems works in a similar manner.

Comment: Can we migrate some of these comments to an answer.

Comment: There is a tutorial introduction on PBS at https://albertsk.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/pbs.pdf

Answer (score 3):

This is a shell script file (what you called an "sh file"). However, it also contains directives for the [PBS scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Batch_System). This is a system often found in high performance clusters where multiple users need to be able to submit jobs that are then put into a queuing system and launched when the resources become available.

In general, any lines in a shell script that start with a `#` are comments and are ignored by the shell script interpreter (e.g. bash). This is most often used for commenting code, but a famous exception is the [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) (e.g. `#!/bin/bash`) which is ignored by the shell interpreter (it starts with an `#`), but is read by the kernel to decide what interpreter should be given the script.

PBS uses a similar approach: the `#PBS` comments are read by PBS when setting up the parameters for the job that is described in the shell script. So, this line:

```
#PBS  -l mem=900mb,walltime=25000:00:00,cput=25000:00:00,nodes=1:ppn=1
```

is telling PBS to run this with 900M of memory, on a single node and whatever else the various options may mean.

Finally, the `cd $PBS_DIRECTORY` is a normal shell command. `$PBS_DIRECTORY` is a variable which, presumably, has been set to point to the directory where the work should be performed. So the first step in the script is to `cd` into that directory, to move into it, and then run the `sample_file.x` script located in that directory.

For any more detail than this, please consult the administrator of the PBS cluster you are using.

Answer (score -1):

It does look like a shell script. If so, # is the beginning of a comment. In this script, $ is used for variable substitution, i.e., $PBS_O_WORKDIR is substituted by the value of environment variable PBS_O_WORKDIR. `-l` is not a command.

I don't know why a shell script is named something.bat, but you can call it whatever you like. The extension has no meaning.